# glBlendFunc and alpha channel

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency

I'm trying to render some transparent objects using:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

However, I don't get the result I want.

I draw a fully opaque square, and then i draw a semi-transparent square. The colors are just as a I would expect however, the alpha channel is NOT fully white as I want.

Basically I want the following equation:

```
r = old_r*(1.0-a)+r*a;
g = old_g*(1.0-a)+g*a;
b = old_b*(1.0-a)+b*a;
a = old_a + a;
```

Is this possible to achieve using glBlendFunc or do I have to resort to shaders and multiple FBOs for read-back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You basically want separate blend functions for color and alpha, and this is achieved by using [glBlendFuncSeparate](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFuncSeparate.xml):

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

Does the blend func you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just draw your opaque square, then check the alpha channel. If it's not showing up as fully white when a known-opaque square is rendered, you may have a problem with some other setting.

Comment: If i just draw the opaque square its fully white, however if i draw the semi-transparent over it then it is no longer fully white.